# Number of Hospitals in the US with emergency departments

Tags: data-request, usa, medical

How many US hospitals have emergency departments?

Answer (score 0):

[Hospital General Information](https://www.kaggle.com/cms/hospital-general-information)

General information & quality ratings for almost all US hospitals

This file contains general information about all hospitals that have been registered with Medicare, including their addresses, type of hospital, and ownership structure. It also contains information about the quality of each hospital, in the form of an overall rating (1-5, where 5 is the best possible rating & 1 is the worst), and whether the hospital scored above, same as, or below the national average for a variety of measures.

This data was updated by CMS on July 25, 2017. CMS' overall rating includes 60 of the 100 measures for which data is collected & reported on the [Hospital Compare website](https://www.medicare.gov/hospitalcompare/search.html). Each of the measures has different collection/reporting dates, so it is impossible to specify exactly which time period this dataset covers.

For more information about the [timeframes for each measure](https://www.medicare.gov/hospitalcompare/Data/Data-Updated.html)

For more information about the [data itself, APIs and a variety of formats](https://data.medicare.gov/Hospital-Compare)

The below links might be helpful

---

[DATA.GOV](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/hospitals-dcdfc)

This database contains locations of Hospitals for 50 states and Washington D.C. , Puerto Rico and US territories. The dataset only includes hospital facilities and does not include nursing homes.

---

[DATA.Medicare.Gov](https://data.medicare.gov/data/hospital-compare)

---

[HealthData.gov](https://healthdata.gov/dataset/hospital-general-information)

---